# Quill-Mention: Mention Dropdown does not reopen after typing some mistyped string and deleting

Tags: angular, quill, mention, ngx-quill

Below given is the code I'm trying to implement.
Here, if I type my desired name, the `source()` function calls the `renderList()` and runs properly because `matches` is not empty.
The problem arises that if I mistype (or, write a name that does not exist, i.e., `searchTerm` does not match any name), the `matches` list becomes empty causing the `renderList()` to not able to show any list and thus closing the mention dropdown list. Now, if I delete the mistyped part, the mention dropdown should've reappeared, but it is reappearing only when I delete the whole `searchTerm` because it finds the `mentionChar` and then triggers the `onOpen()` method.

```
if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
    renderList(values, searchTerm);
} else {
    const matches: any[] = [];
    values.forEach((entry: { searchValue: any; value: string }) => {
        if (
            entry.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        ) {
            matches.push(entry);
        }
    });
    renderList(matches, searchTerm);
}
```

Is there any way that to not close the mention dropdown in case any matches are not found. Given I have the requirement to not show any suggestions if typed wrong or no matches found.

I tried to find any solution on Github's Quill Mention repo, but couldn't find any.